# How to ensure that each test runs with a clean render using JEST/RTL?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am unit testing a component form. The idea here is that the submit button is `disabled` and gets `enabled` when the form input is not empty. I'm doing that with a controlled input.

I have two tests in this example, the first one works fine, but the second one doesn't, this happens because of the changes made by the first test, the `inputValue` state changes and doesn't reset for the second test.

What I want to know is how can I reset states between tests?

I've tried rendering the component within each test, tried using `beforeEach`, among other  solutions that I found, but without any success.

This is a sample of my component:

```
const FormInputConfig = () => {
   const [formIsValidState, setFormIsValidState] = useState(true)
   const [setInputValue, inputValue] = useState('')


   const inputChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, i: number) => {  
      const value = e.target.value
      
      setInputValue(value)
      setFormIsValidState(formIsValid)
   }

   const formatFormHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      // do something
   }

   return (
      <form
         onSubmit={formatFormHandler}
      >
         <input 
            onChange={e => inputChangeHandler(e)}
            value={inputValue}
         />
         <button disabled={formIsValidState}>
            Inserir Produto
         </button>
      </form>
   )
}

export default FormInputConfig
```

This is the test:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { store, Provider } from 'test-setup'

import FormInputConfig from './FormInputConfig'

const renderFormInputConfig = () => {
   const { container } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
         <FormInputConfig />
      </Provider>
   )

   const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'Inserir Produto'})

   return { container, submitButton }
}

describe('full form input', () => {
   test('submit button should be set enable if all inputs are valid', () => {
      const { submitButton } = renderFormInputConfig()
      const inputEl = screen.getByRole('textbox')

      expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled()

      fireEvent.change(inputEl, {target: {value: 'Mock Product'}})

      expect(submitButton).not.toBeDisabled()
   })

   test('form should be cleared after submission', () => {
      const { submitButton } = renderFormInputConfig()
      const inputEl = screen.getByRole('textbox')

      expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled()
      
      fireEvent.change(allInputs[0], {target: {value: 'Mock Product'}})

      expect(submitButton).not.toBeDisabled()
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are importing something called `store` which you are using as a provider. This store changes so if it is passed to a new Provider in the second test the store remains changed. What you need for this example is a factory function which is a function like `createStore()` which returns the object that the store is instead of returning the variable. This way everytime you call `createStore()` you can be sure that you are working with a fresh object.

Comment: I get that, this is causing problems in other tests, but in this specific case the problem is due to the local state `inputValue`.  This is the state I need to restore. The store is there so the test doesn't break.

Comment: Have you also tried unmounting in an `afterEach` statement? https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#unmount

Answer (score 0):

i was facing something similar to this too but i was using `vitest`.

To solve this i had to do:

```
// Unmounts React trees that were mounted with render
afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});
```

In my test `setUpFiles.ts` file that runs before each tests.

Hope this helps